# What is this strange second camera?

Tags: camera, filming

I don't know is this is the correct place to ask this but ...

I've watched several "making of" of current movies and noticed a thing i cannot explain.

**What is this strange "secondary" camera you can see near the main camera?**

Image: 
[image]

Reference:  (5:52 and 6:50)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a specially built enclosure called a [Sound Blimp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_blimp), for a still camera, which renders it completely silent, so they can shoot stills without clicks and beeps disturbing the filming.

Comment: Thank you ... I almost thought it was some kind of depth camera to help in later 3Difying the movie :)